# Sections to projection morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a complete DVR, $X, Y$ schemes over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Denote by $f:X \times_R Y \to X$ be a natural projection morphism. Does the morphism $f$ has a section i.e., a $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$-morphism $s:X \to X \times_R Y$ such that $f \circ s=\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to «is there a morphism $h:X\to Y$ over $\operatorname{Spec}R$?».

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand.

Comment: So if you take $X=\operatorname{R}$, for example, and $Y$ a scheme with no $R$-points, then you get a counterxample.